# Mouse and Keyboard Not working after upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 16.10

Tags: 16.04, unity, upgrade, 16.10, mouse-pointer

I have looked into this topic for some time and there seems to be zero solutions, so here is my question. I upgraded from Ubuntu Unity 16.04lts to Ubuntu 16.10 using these steps.

1. Enter software and updates
2. go into updates tab
3. turn notify me of a new ubuntu version to>>> any version of linux
4. open terminal and enter

   `sudo do-release-upgrade`

After the installation processes my laptop HP Laptop rebooted and after reboot I was unable to use the mouse and keyboard. When I shut down my laptop everything looks fine until I get to the user login page and since I can't use my mouse or keyboard I am locked out from my computer.
Help What Do I Do?

update: It's is a laptop so I am using the laptop keypad and keyboard. I tried plugging in external mouse and keyboard but they don't work either. 
Thank you.

Comment: You really need to include information on *how* your mouse and keyboard are connected to your computer.

Comment: @pzkpfw My computer is a laptop and I don't have an external keyboard and mouse . I just use the built in mouse and keyboard with my laptop. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you.